# React Native, unable to save camara snaps

Tags: react-native, expo

I could't save Expo based camera captured image to phone. Getting error

*[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoMediaLibrary.MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync')]*

```
export class Camera extends Component {

  takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
      await MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(photo.uri);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Camera
          ref={(ref) => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
        >
          <FontAwesome name="camera" onPress={() => this.takePicture()} />
        </Camera>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Complete code as below

https://github.com/Alhydra/react-native-camera-expo-exmple/blob/master/App.js

Comment: have you imported the library? `import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';`

Comment: yes I did import